# Use int to convert decimal to bianary

Tags: python

I want to convert number 168 to binary using `int`,
It report error

```
In [11]: int(168, base=2)                                                                                                                             

----> 1 int(168, base=2)

TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

I read the doc and tried alternativly

```
In [13]: int("168", base=2)                                                                                                                           
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 2: '168'
```

I learned that `bin` could get the job done

```
In [16]: bin(168)                                                                                                                                     
Out[16]: '0b10101000'
```

How could I use `int` to do it?

Comment: You can't - `int()` creates an integer type from a string (there is no binary type). To convert integers to binary strings you've already found `bin()`, similarly `format(168, 'b')` does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `int` with `base=2` is to convert a string value in a given base (binary for `base=2`) to integer and not vice versa to convert into binary what you are trying to do.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)

> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use int() to convert things **to** an integer, the simplest way of converting from number to binary is the function bin(). Just so you know, int() can also convert binary to an integer.